# How to compute DIR@FAR1% for face identification?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Recently, In some papers face recognition approaches are being evaluated through a new proposed protocol, names as closed-set and open-set face identification over LFW dataset. For open-set one, the Rank-1 accuracy is reported as **Detection and Identification Rate (DIR)** at a **fixed False Alarm/Acceptance Rate (FAR)**. I have a gallery and a probe set and am using KNN for classification, however I don't know how to compute the DIR@FAR1%.

Update:

Specifically, what is ambiguous to me is fixating the FAR at a fixed threshold, or how the curves such as ROC, precision-recall and etc are plotted for face recognition. What does the threshold in the following paragraph mean?

> Hence the performance is evaluated based on (i) Rank-1 detection and identification rate (DIR), which is the fraction of genuine probes matched correctly at Rank-1, and not rejected at a given threshold, and (ii) the false alarm rate (FAR) of the rejection step (i.e. the fraction of impostor probe images which are not rejected). We report the DIR vs. FAR curve describing the trade-off between true Rank-1 identifications and false alarms.

The reference paper is downloadable [here](http://www.cse.msu.edu/rgroups/biometrics/Publications/Face/BestRowdenetal_UnconstrainedFaceRecognition_TIFS2014.pdf). 
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Your question is too generic and contains too little references and context. You should add some links and references and try to be more specific about what you are asking.

Comment: your right. I just added some more details. If still generic, I can add more details.

Comment: Can you add links to the papers/techniques you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the DIR metric was established by the Biometrics society. This metric includes both the detection (exceeding some threshold) and the identification (rank). Let the gallery consists of a set of enrolled users in a biometric
database and the probe set may contain users who may or may not be present
in the database. Let *g* and *p* are two elements of the gallery and probe sets respectively. Moreover, let the probe set include two disjoint subsets: *P1* including the samples of those who belong to the gallery subjects and *P0* including those who do not.

Assume *s(p,g)*  is a similarity score between a probe and a gallery elements, *t* is a threshold and *k* is the identification rank. Then *DIR* is given by:

[image]

You can find the complete formula in this reference:
Poh, N., et al. "Description of Metrics For the Evaluation of Biometric Performance." Seventh Framework Programme of Biometrics Evaluation and Testing (2012): 1-22.